# Algebraic Geometry: Flatness is equivalent to being scheme-theoretically dense?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Mumford's penultimate draft for his Algebraic Geometry book, he says in p.144 (followed by a definition 4.12 which I copied here):

> Def 4.12. Let R be a valuation ring, and let $\eta$ (resp. $o$) be the generic (resp. closed) point of Spec R. Let $f:X\rightarrow$ Spec R be a flat morphism of finite type (by Proposition 4.5, this means: $O_X$ is a sheaf of torsion-free R-modules). Then we say that the closed fibre $X_o$ of $f$ is a specialization over R of the generic fibre $X_\eta$.
>
> Note that the flatness of $f$ is equivalent to saying that $X_\eta$ is scheme-theoretically dense in $X$.

Why is this true?

Comment: The target is pretty important here. Is he assuming $X$ noetherian? I'd like to make some argument about associated points but I'm afraid of the non-noetherian case.

Comment: Hmm.. it doesn't seem like $X$ is assumed to be noetherian.. Can I still hear your argument?

Comment: I think what I have in mind is detailed in III.9 of Hartshorne. The point is that schematically dense in that case just means you contain all the associated points. So the statement is that all the associated points map to the generic point. So no non-zero elements of $R$ map to zero-divisors in $\mathcal{O}_X$. [The book you're reading sticks in blanket assumptions every once and a while, so there's a chance of this. I remember he declares all schemes to be separated at some point.]

Comment: [The book you're reading sticks in blanket assumptions every once and a while]-I agree. And even if $X$ is not noetherian, I think the proof will use a similar idea. Thanks!